# Как обновить данные одной строки данными из другой строки?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица *sales* с полями *model, color, price*. Вытаскиваю данные из строки с `id='12'` и пытаюсь их вставить с `id='13'`:

```
UPDATE sales SET (model, color, price) =
(SELECT model, color, price FROM sales WHERE id = '12') WHERE id = '13'
```

Но ничего не получается.

Пытаюсь cделать, основываясь на [этом примере](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_(SQL)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в *mysql* можно сделать так (объединить таблицу саму с собой):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eac00/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table sales (id int, model int, color int);
insert into sales values
  (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2);

update sales a
  inner join sales b on a.id = 1 and b.id = 2
  set a.model = b.model, a.color = b.color;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from sales
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eac00/1/0)**:

```
| id | model | color |
|----|-------|-------|
|  1 |     2 |     2 |
|  2 |     2 |     2 |
```

Comment: А как вы относитесь к написанию зарезервированных слов SQL заглавными буквами? По-моему, `INSERT INTO sales VALUES` и т.д. несколько упрощает восприятие запроса.

Comment: @Regent, отрицательно. во-первых, сочетание букв разного размера в одной фразе, на мой взгляд, выглядит неэстетично, во-вторых, применительно к *sql* это выглядит даже несколько абсурдно, как мне кажется: ведь это даже не аббревиатуры, а слова естественного английского языка (*ibm*-овский *sequel* — это *structured english query language*, о чём, наверно, не стоит забывать).

Comment: Так ведь это программный код, а не обычный текст - применить правила русского и английского языков здесь не получится. В плане эстетики, конечно, у каждого свои фломастеры, но разве `SELECT name FROM table INNER JOIN table2 ON a = b WHERE x = 1 AND y = 2` (особенно в несколько строк, а не в одну) не лучше для восприятия, чем `select name from table inner join table2 on a = b where x = 1 and y = 2`?

Comment: @Regent, *sequel*, насколько я помню, как раз и задумывался как «почти» естественный язык запросов.

Comment: @Regent, *не лучше для восприятия?*, нет, я думаю, выделение **слишком** большого количества **ключевых** слов в **предложении** лишь **ухудшает** его **восприятие**.

Comment: Полностью согласен с alexander barakin

Comment: Тут ведь идея в разделении названий полей и слов, относящихся к самому SQL, чтобы можно было сразу отделить одно от другого, а не сидеть и думать: "`coalesce` - это поле такое в таблице или что-то редкое из SQL?". И как последняя попытка в защиту идеи - полу-искусственный пример: `select selectId from forms where here = 1`

Comment: @Regent, резонно, но: во-первых, ключевые слова не даст использовать в качестве идентификаторов сам *sql*, во-вторых, тут уже затрагивается культура выбора «хороших и выразительных» имён для идентификаторов.